# wordpress installation error is_readable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i got an error while installing wordpress.

i tried using vhost.conf

i had an parallels plesk panel.

kindly help. thanks in advance.

this is the error.

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com/wp-config.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (d:/inetpub/vhosts//maxires.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\httpdocs\wp-load.php on line 31

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\httpdocs\wp-load.php:31) in D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\httpdocs\wp-load.php on line 56

Answer (score 0):

> This error means that the PHP script is trying to access a folder for
>   which access is not allowed. For security reasons, PHP options for
>   domains hosted in Parallels Plesk Panel (Plesk) allow access to the
>   /tmp and http(s)docs folders only by default. Restrictions are limited
>   by the open_basedir PHP variable for each virtual host separately.
>   Source: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/432

From what I can see you've got your WordPress files installed outside of your hosting web root folder.

Your hosting is as follows: `D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\`

You will have a folder within `D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\` called `httpdocs` (`D:\inetpub\vhosts\maxires.com\httpdocs`).

You need to have all of your WordPress files kept within `httpdocs` for PHP to be able to read the files.

It is much easier to use the Plesk "one-click installer" ("applications"?) so that your server instsalls WordPress to the right location. This is guaranteed to work as the hosting company have configured Plesk to be able to install WordPress - not you - so they'll be responsible if it's problematic.

Comment: thanks for the help. actually i'm trying to rehost a designed wordpress website using wordpress duplicator. now i had changed the is_readable to none in the settings of the parallels plesk panel. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

goto settings in the plesk panel and then click on php settings

then change "open_basedir" to "none".

thats it worked well for me.